# android : how to fetch default application for backup process?

Tags: java, android, backup

I'm trying to fetch the default applications (video, images, contact, sms) for backup process. How can i do this? Is there any default method for to do this?

Comment: But why do you want to backup only default apps?

Comment: I didn't need default apps. If you're having some codes for getting all application then, send me.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any difference between the default(apps installed along with the android OS) and apps installed later by user. As far as I know there is no way you can know that. Ask or Search this in [Android Developers](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers?lnk=srg&hl=en) google groups to get a confirmation.
EDIT:
Following code gets the names of all installed apps. Similarly you can get Packageinfo as well.

```
private void getInstalledApps() {
 PackageManager packageManager=this.getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> applist=packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);

    Iterator<ApplicationInfo> it=applist.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        ApplicationInfo pk=(ApplicationInfo)it.next();

        String appname = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(pk).toString();
        installedapplist.add(appname);
    }
}
```